# Using weightedMedian function in matrixStats

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to find a function in r that successfully calculates the weighted median from a dataframe. By that I mean I want to find the median of a set of values by incorporating their weights (or number of times occurred). From reading other Stack Overflow threads I found matrixStats function, weightedMedian. However, I cannot seem to get it to output the correct answer for my test dataset. Example and code below.

```
# df values are 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20
# weighted median should be 10

## create df
testdf4 <- data.frame(
  Mark = c(10, 5, 20),
  Frequency = c(3, 4, 2)
)

## order by mark
testdf4 <- testdf4[order(testdf4$Mark),]

## find median
testdf4_grouped <- testdf4 %>%
  select(Mark, Frequency) %>%
  summarise(Median_Grade = 
              weightedMedian(testdf4$Mark, testdf4$Frequency))
```

The resulting output is 8.57 when it should be 10? I am very new to r so I'm thinking this is a syntax issue I am facing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you need weighted mean or median? weighted mean comes out to be 10. `weighted.mean(testdf4$Mark, testdf4$Frequency)`

Comment: I do actually need median rather than mean, but thank you for your response!